# How do i make colour detection in turtle

Tags: python, colors, turtle-graphics, detection

I have a python turtle program which is displayed below.

i want to be able to stop game when turtle touches black or touches line but i cant find any help online!!!

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import time
from turtle import *
import winsound
#while True:
#    player1 = input("enter player1 name\n")
#    break
#while True:
#    player2 = input("enter player2 name\n")
#    print("Please click on window titled pacman")
#    break


setup(600, 600)
Screen()
title("Rendering")
horse2 = Turtle()
horse2.shape("triangle")
horse2.color("blue")
#making the map

map1 = Turtle()
map1.color("black")
map1.shape("square")
map1.forward(100)
map1.left(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(180)
map1.forward(50)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(100)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.penup()
map1.left(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.pendown()
map1.forward(50)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.penup()
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(90)
map1.pendown()
map1.forward(50)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.penup()
map1.forward(50)
map1.pendown()
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.forward(50)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(200)
map1.forward(40)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(400)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(500)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(450)
map1.penup()
map1.forward(50)
map1.pendown()
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(500)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(100)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(100)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(180)
map1.forward(50)
map1.penup()
map1.forward(50)
map1.forward(50)
map1.pendown()
map1.left(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(180)
map1.forward(100)
map1.left(180)
map1.forward(150)
map1.right(180)
map1.forward(150)
map1.penup()
map1.forward(50)
map1.forward(100)
map1.right(90)
map1.pendown()
map1.forward(150)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(100)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.right(180)
map1.penup()
map1.forward(100)
map1.penup()
map1.forward(200)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(90)
map1.forward(10)
map1.right(90)
map1.pendown()
map1.forward(50)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.right(90)
map1.forward(50)
map1.left(90)
map1.penup()
map1.forward(50)
#making the map
showturtle()
hideturtle()
horse2.penup()
horse2.goto(-250, -100)
title("Pacman")

def k3():
    horse2.right(90)

def k2():
    horse2.left(90)
    if horse2.xcor() > 250:
        print(player2+" wins")
        logging.basicConfig(filename=("bobobwinner.log"), filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(message)s')
        logging.warning(player2+' won')

def k1():
    horse2.forward(20)

onkey(k1, "w")
onkey(k2, "a")
onkey(k3, "d")
#onkey(k4, "Left")
#onkey(k5, "Down")

listen()
mainloop()
```

i have no error message however i have failed time after time to succeed. Please can someone help. I am well aware that turtle is a very limited game engine so if this is not possible is anybody aware how i could code my own module to supplement for colour detection in turtle.

Comment: `turtle` doesn't have function to detect collision. `turtle` is built on top of module `tkinter` and its widget `Canvas` which have some functions to check if object overlap other object but it can be hard to use it with lines create with turtle. If you build it with white and black blocks and player will move from block to block then you could keep postions of black blocks and check if player's position is not on black block (and move it back)

Comment: Next time, it'd be good to prove a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @furas notes in his comment, we don't have color detection in turtle though we can get object detection at the tkinter level and then check colors.  Below is a different approach: we build all the walls out of turtles and use distance calculations, in conjunction with the wall's length, to detect collision:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

walls = []

def make_wall(turtle, distance):
    turtle.forward(distance / 2)
    clone = turtle.clone()
    clone.shapesize(stretch_len=distance/CURSOR_SIZE)
    clone.showturtle()
    turtle.forward(distance / 2)

    walls.append(clone)

def collision(turtle):
    tx, ty = turtle.position()

    for wall in walls:

        if wall.distance(turtle) < CURSOR_SIZE / 2:
            wall.color('red')
            return True

        wx, wy = wall.position()
        heading = wall.heading()
        _, stretch_len, _ = wall.shapesize()
        half_length = stretch_len * (CURSOR_SIZE + 1) / 2

        if heading in [0, 180]:  # horizontal wall

            if abs(ty - wy) < CURSOR_SIZE / 2 and abs(tx - wx) < half_length:
                wall.color('red')
                return True

        elif heading in [90, 270]:  # vertical wall

            if abs(tx - wx) < CURSOR_SIZE / 2 and abs(ty - wy) < half_length:
                wall.color('red')
                return True

    return False

def k3():
    horse.right(90)

def k2():
    horse.left(90)

def k1():
    screen.onkey(None, "w")

    horse.forward(15)

    if horse.xcor() > 250:
        screen.title("Player wins!")
    elif collision(horse):
        screen.title("Collision!")
    else:
        screen.onkey(k1, "w")

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)
screen.title("Rendering")
screen.tracer(False)

mapper = Turtle()
mapper.shape("square")
mapper.hideturtle()
mapper.penup()
mapper.shapesize(stretch_wid=1/CURSOR_SIZE)

# making the map

make_wall(mapper, 100)
mapper.left(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.left(180)
make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 100)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)

mapper.left(90)
mapper.forward(50)

make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.left(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)

mapper.forward(50)
mapper.left(90)

make_wall(mapper, 100)
mapper.left(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.left(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)

mapper.forward(50)
mapper.right(90)

make_wall(mapper, 100)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 240)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 400)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 500)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 450)

mapper.forward(50)
mapper.right(90)

make_wall(mapper, 500)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 100)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 100)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.left(180)
make_wall(mapper, 50)

mapper.forward(100)
mapper.left(90)

make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.left(180)
make_wall(mapper, 100)
mapper.left(180)
make_wall(mapper, 150)
mapper.right(180)
make_wall(mapper, 150)

mapper.forward(150)
mapper.right(90)

make_wall(mapper, 150)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 150)
mapper.left(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)

mapper.right(180)
mapper.forward(350)
mapper.left(90)
mapper.forward(10)
mapper.right(90)

make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.left(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)
mapper.right(90)
make_wall(mapper, 50)

horse = Turtle()
horse.shape("triangle")
horse.color("blue")
horse.penup()
horse.goto(-250, -100)

screen.onkey(k1, "w")
screen.onkey(k2, "a")
screen.onkey(k3, "d")

screen.listen()
screen.tracer(True)
screen.title("Maze")
screen.mainloop()
```

This is complicated, particularly the `collision()` function, but it basically works.  I've simplified your original example slightly to remove items that have nothing to do with the issue in question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a vital help.