# Turtle collision with its own drawings in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I want to know if a turtle is in the same place as it was before (for a maze game in python).
I tried:

```
import turtle
c == 1
a = turtle.Turtle()
b = turtle.Turtle()
b.fd(100)
while c == 1:
  a.fd(10)
if a.is_collided_with(b):
  print("Collision")
break
```

The problem is that it says that there is no such thing as `.is_collided_with()` (it might because I'm using python 3.9.1).
Is there a way to do this without using several turtles?
Thanks

Comment: `turtle` never had `is_collided_with()` - where did you find it?

Comment: can't you simply get its position and keep on some list and after move check if new position is on this list?

Comment: You could keep track of already visited locations in a set, or you could define tiles and each tile keeps track of whether it was visited by the turtle or not.

Comment: Looks like the indenting got messed up. You can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the surrounding code, what we really want is:

```
if a.distance(b) < 5:
    print("Collision")
```

As turtles wander their floating point plane, two turtles right atop each other may not be at the same exact coordinates.  The `5` value can be set to however close you want to consider a collision to be.

As far as `distance()` goes, it can take another turtle, as in your example, or it can take a position from a list of visited positions.

> I want something that detects a collision with the turtle drawing.

Here's a [turtle-based maze that does that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081463/5771269) by making the walls themselves turtles (though they look like lines) and uses the distance function above to detect collision.

Comment: It means that it will print collision only when the turtle toches a turtle; I want something that detects a collision with the turtle drawing. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @JonathanDrukker, I've added a pointer to a turtle maze that works the way you described but is implemented the way I described.